# error CS1002: ; expected but I think I have the semicolon. I don't know what's wrong

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to add damage for a health bar in unity 2d. I tried to use a simple subtraction on a variable and it came with the error but I have the semicolon. If someone could help I would be grateful.

Here is the error - Assets\PlayerDamage.cs(17,27): error CS1002: ; expected

Here is the line of code its pointing towards - health -- 0.1f;

full code below

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerDamage : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float health;

    void Update()
    {
        health = GameObject.Find("Health Bar").GetComponent<HealthBar>().healthX;

        void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
        {
            if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") 
            {
                health -- 0.1f;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `health -= 0.1f;`. `health--;` is a self-contained statement to decrement `health` by `1`, so needs a semicolon after it.

Comment: In think you want `health -= 0.1f;` which is short for `heath = health - 0.1f;`

Answer (score 4):

This is not valid C# code.

If you're trying to subtract health by 10% then you want

```
health = health - 0.1f * health;
```

or

```
health -= health * 0.1f;
```

If you're trying to subtract the value .1 from health you want

```
health -= 0.1f;
```

The `health --` is a statement in and of itself meaning "decrement health by 1"; all statements need a `;`. So if you continued with that, then you'd have the still incorrect

```
health --; 0.1f;
```

which is still meaningless because now you have the expression `0.1f` followed by a `;`, which won't compile either (with CS0201).